# Vue and "vuedraggable", update data in subcomponents?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a list which is draggable and I use there "vuedraggable" component.

Inside this list I have 3 subcomponents.

1 input and 2 selectboxes, I have there *@change* to update informations.

If I do the order of "tasks", it works perfectly and I send to backend correct data, but in frontend in subcomponents is the data not updated. In selectbox and input box I see the data on the same place.

My vuejs example:

```
<draggable v-model="tasks" draggable=".task">
    <div v-for="task in tasks" class="task">
        
        <task-title-update :task="task"></task-title-update>
        <task-assignee :task="task"></task-assignee>
        <task-priority :task="task"></task-priority>
    </div>
</draggable>
```

Is there possible to keep this subcomponents and update the data correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on the event with one of the events that vue-draggable provides, try using @end or @start, then you can put the logic from the `@change` into those events.

Comment: is this not related to my prop "task"? What does it mean `@start` and `@end`, I think `@change` is not related to my problem?

Comment: see here for the "typical use"
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#for-vuejs-20

Comment: I missed to set :key`<div v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" class="task">` after that everything works fine. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: great, I would still recommend using the custom events provided by the package it will give you greater flexibility.